# Separate light sensor class receives "System services not available to Activities before onCreate()" in Debug

Tags: java, android

I'm working on code that implements a light sensor through a different class.

It is almost identical to this one, I just named the class LightActivity and changed some of the names of the variables: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html

I've tried to initialize it on onCreate but the logcat gives me:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.miaga.wholemilk/com.example.miaga.wholemilk.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
```

Because of this code:

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView lxChangingValue, confirmWorking;
Button stopLx;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    lxChangingValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lxChangingValue);
    confirmWorking = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.confirmWorking);

    LightActivity firstLightActivity = new LightActivity();

}

}
```

LightActivity Class:

```
import android.hardware.SensorManager;


public class LightActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener{

private final SensorManager lightManager;
private final Sensor lightSensor;

public LightActivity(){
    lightManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    lightSensor = lightManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);
}

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        lightManager.registerListener(this, lightSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        lightManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }


    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    }

}
```

I'm definitely sure it is because of

```
LightActivity firstLightActivity = new LightActivity();
```

but I have no clue how to initialize it without it setting off the error, and I do not wish to put all of this code in MainActivity. Is there a different way to initialize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have no clue how to initialize it

That is because you do not initialize it. **Never** create an instance of an activity yourself.

> I do not wish to put all of this code in MainActivity

Pass a `SensorManager` into the constructor of your to-be-renamed `LightActivity`.

Comment: What do you mean by renamed?

Comment: @Mia: Well, it should no longer subclass `Activity`, and `LightActivity` is a strange name in that case.

Comment: LightActivity also has onResume and onPause, similar to the android documentation - I will edit my question to include my full code

Comment: @Mia: You will need to get rid of those, or forward calls to them from your real activity.

Comment: like this?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15074905/sensor-activity-in-android